# Вычисление синуса,используя ряд Тейлора

Tags: c++, c, математика, численные-методы, тригонометрия

Учитель задал написать программу,вычисляющую значение sin(x) рядом Тейлора.Проблема в том,что не понимаю как ввести понятие периода.Иначе говоря чем большее число мы вводим,тем большее значение получаем.
Вот код:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <math.h>  
double my_sin(double x);  
int main(void)  
{  
    double a,x;  
    scanf("%le",&x);  
    a=my_sin(x);  
    printf("%le",(double)a);  
    return 0;}  
    
double my_sin(double x)  
{  
  double sum=x, h, eps=1.e-16; int i=4;  
h=(-1)*(pow(x,3)/6);   
do{
    sum+=h;  //Формула очередного слагаемого  
    h*=(-1)*((pow(x,2)/((i)*(i+1))));  
    i+=2;}     
while( fabs(h)>eps );  
return sum;  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Область сходимости, как мне правильно подсказали в комментарриях, для этого ряда не ограничена. Про определение области сходимости - смотрите [статью](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%8F%D0%B4_%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0)

Формула [image: синуса через ряд]

Но, как я понимаю алгоритм, для больших х выгоднее вычислять через период, или пользуясь тем, что

[image: (формула тройного угла)]

Comment: Простите пожалуйста,но по каким-то причинам сайт не открывается,можете как-то по-другому прислать или вкратце объяснить,если не трудно?

Comment: Поправил, да там просто ссылка на вики

Comment: Спасибо,а можете рассказать или показать как реализовать период от 0 до 2pi,для синуса,в программе,меня больше всего это интересует.

Comment: ну как, для x от 0 до 1 - понятно, ряд. До пи поплолам - по формуле тройного угла. А дальше - график же симметричный...

Comment: С каких пор ряд Маклорена для синуса перестал сходиться вне интервала `(-1, 1)`?

Comment: @wololo - прошу прощения, глупость сморозил :-) поправил

Comment: @S.H - 3 вопроса.Вы имеете ввиду,что я могу не вводит период,если буду пользоваться формулой sin3x=3*sinx-4(sinx)^3?Как вводить эту формулу,sin3x=3*sinx-4*pow(sinx,3)?И где именно в коде его записать?

Comment: при больших х у вас в членах ряда будут появляться в числителе и знаменателе большие числа. Работать с ними на С не очень удобно. Поэтому надо оптимизировать - пользоваться периодичностью. А формулу тройного угла использовать вообще необязательно

Comment: Можно период записать так: После scanf написать while((x-2*PI)>2*PI) {x=x-2*PI;}?

Comment: По моему, чтобы воспользоваться периодичностью, нужно введенное число поделить на два пи с остатком. От остатка посчитать синус.

Answer (score 5):

Ну, пользуясь периодичностью и нечетностью синуса, я бы делал так - переводил x в значение от 0 до pi/2:

```
const double pi = 3.14159265358979323846;

double Sin(double x, double eps = 1e-12)
{
    int sign = (x < 0) ? -1 : 1;
    // Приводим к [0, 2*pi]
    x = fmod(fabs(x),2*pi);
    // Приводим к [0, pi]
    if (x > pi) { x -= pi; sign *= -1; }
    // Приводим к [0, pi/2]
    if (x > pi/2) x = pi - x;

    double t = x, s = x;
    for(int n = 3; fabs(t) > eps; n += 2)
        s += t = -t*x*x/n/(n-1);
    return s*sign;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    cout << "sin(121.5*pi) = " << Sin(121.5*pi) << endl;
    cout << "sin(-pi/6)    = " << Sin(-pi/6) << endl;
    cout << "sin(3*pi/2)   = " << Sin(3*pi/2) << endl;
    cout << "sin(300*pi)   = " << Sin(300*pi) << endl;
}
```

А уж тут сходимость молниеносная :) Для 10<sup>-13</sup> хватает 9 итераций...

Вот, посмотрите для больших случайных чисел: https://ideone.com/D2iZtp